# Can a wild shaped druid benefit from enlarge person?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, druid, wild-shape, creature-size

Can a humanoid druid wild shape and then have enlarge person cast on them and become a larger form of what they are wild shaped as?

Enlarge person is a transmutation effect and not polymorph like wild shape.

So, would the two effects work together?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## No.

*Enlarge person* has no effect on a wild shaped druid. The [transmutation (polymorph) rules](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/magic.html#polymorph) say a polymorphed creature does not benefit from size-altering spells. Wild shape is a polymorph effect due to functioning like *beast shape I* and other polymorph spells. Thus, a size-altering spell like *enlarge person* has no effect with wild shape.

> You can only be affected by one polymorph spell at a time. If a new
>   polymorph spell is cast on you (or you activate a polymorph effect,
>   such as wild shape), you can decide whether or not to allow it to
>   affect you, taking the place of the old spell. **In addition, other
>   spells that change your size have no effect on you while you are under
>   the effects of a polymorph spell.**

Comment: A good point. I have modified the answer to point out that wild shape is a polymorph effect.

Comment: I had missed that line buried inside the polymorph rules, thanks

Comment: Yeah great callout. I expected the answer to be some convoluted thing about keeping/changing type/subtype. this is way more straight forward.

Comment: It should in theory still apply to the alternate class features of totem transformations. They just gain aspects of the animal, and don't actually polymorph. An enlarged bear shaman isn't something to mess around with.

Comment: In addition, the wildshaped druid doesn't register as a "person" in the sense of spell targeting anymore, as by design of polymorph-type spells and effects. So spells like "hold person" would fail on a wildshaped druid as well.

Comment: @Anonymous That is incorrect. Polymorph effects do *not* change your creature type. The polymorph rules never say your creature type changes. There are extremely few effects in the game that actually change your type. Some effects give you subtypes (like the higher level elemental body spells) while others have you be treated as a type for certain effects (like Androids's constructed trait).